# How can i combine a case insensitive search with a case sensitive replace in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, suppose I have the following text:

```
"Constants cons are CONTAGIOUS"
```

I want all the "cons" replaced irrespective of case, but preserving case on the replace.

For example, suppose I want to put bold tags around them, I would want the output to be:

```
"<b>Con</b>stants <b>cons</b> are <b>CON</b>TAGIOUS"
```

In JavaScript, I have tried:

```
var re = new RegExp("con", 'ig');
var newText = text.replace(re,"<b>" + "con" + "</b>");
```

This does a case insensitive search but I lose the case on the replace. Is there a way to preserve case on the replace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@JordanRunning](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179125/jordan-running) has pointed out in a comment,
a simple solution is to refer to the matched string in the replacement string using `$&`:

```
"Constants cons are CONTAGIOUS".replace(/con/ig, "<b>$&</b>")
```

Produces:

```
"<b>Con</b>stants <b>con</b>s are <b>CON</b>TAGIOUS"
```

Another alternative (my original suggestion) it using capturing group `(con)`, and reference it in the replacement string with `$1`:

```
"Constants cons are CONTAGIOUS".replace(/(con)/ig, "<b>$1</b>")
```

Comment: You don't need a capture here. [Use `$&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).

Comment: @JordanRunning indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the input in a capturing group `()` and refer back to it in the replacement via `$1`:

```js
var text = "Constants cons are CONTAGIOUS";

var regex = new RegExp("(con)", 'ig');
var newText = text.replace(regex, "<b>$1</b>");

console.log(newText); // "<b>Con</b>stants <b>con</b>s are <b>CON</b>TAGIOUS"
```

---

**Edit:** Thanks @JordanRunning, you don't even need a capturing group in this case, since you are referring back to the complete match:

```js
var text = "Constants cons are CONTAGIOUS";

var regex = new RegExp("con", 'ig');
var newText = text.replace(regex, "<b>$&</b>");

console.log(newText); // "<b>Con</b>stants <b>con</b>s are <b>CON</b>TAGIOUS"
```

Comment: You don't need a capture here. Use `$&`.